# Linked Server transaction stopped by MSDTC

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, msdtc

We've recently installed the newest Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (msoledbsql) as it now supports multi-subnet failover capabilities (detailed here: - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2018/03/30/released-microsoft-ole-db-driver-for-sql-server/)

However we are seeing an issue with queries using linked servers.

When we run a simple query through linked server "test": -

```
select * from test.master.sys.databases;
```

The error returned is: -

```
Msg 8522, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction.
```

I've checked the settings for MSDTC on both servers (source and target) and they seem to be correct.

[image: MSDTC Settings]

I've seen online that this can be fixed by explicitly opening a distributed transaction:-

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRAN
select * from test.master.sys.databases;
ROLLBACK
```

But that errors out with: -

```
Msg 3910, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Transaction context in use by another session.
```

Has anyone seen this before? Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm encountering this as well. Did you find any sort of resolution?